# Pronunciation of s in "is he/is him"

Tags: pronunciation, silent-letter

I would like some clarification on the pronunciation of "s" in "is he/is her/is his"

In the question "Where is he?" you pronounce s as "s" (not
"z" sound) and h is silent.
So is it pronounced "wherisi?" ?

Does the same go for "Where is her sister" or "Who is his friend"?
Or does it depend on the regional English?

**EDIT:**
My doubt started after listening to this bbc podcast:

[Man flu](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/language/theenglishwespeak/2012/11/121127_tews_99_man_flu.shtml)
At second 30 a british woman says "whereisi".  "s sound not z"

Comment: Isee . I understood that the second one is not, but I thought that the one who actually said the sentence was british. What gave her away? Only the s sound?

Comment: Actually, the first woman might be. I hadn't listened carefully enough. She's probably from somewhere in the north of England. But the reason that she puts an /h/ into *he* here, is just that she is speaking unnaturally slowly, and over-enunciating.

Comment: You might want to wait a day or two before selecting an answer. You might get some more interesting and helpful ones! :-)

Comment: ok. I'll wait and see if someone gives some more insight. Anyway, your explanation is already a valuable lesson for me

Comment: I listened to the audio, and it sounds like she says "izz", not "iss", to this American English speaker.  I agree that there is kind of a sibilant noise there, but I think it's a side effect of her very carefully enunciating the H and possibly an [artifact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_artifact) of the recording process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full word *is* is pronounced with a /z/, not with an /s/. If this word is contracted with a preceding word, then if the last sound in that word is unvoiced  then **'s** will be pronounced /s/. Otherwise it will be pronounced /z/.

The Original Poster is correct that if a following pronoun begins with H, then if the word is not stressed, there will usually be no /h/ sound:

- *Where is he*  - /'weər 'ɪz i/
- *Where's his sister* - /'weəz ɪz 'sɪstə/
- *Who's his friend* - /'hu:z ɪz 'frend/
- *What's his name* - /'wɒts ɪz 'neɪm/

Notice that in the last example the word *is* is contracted with the word *what*. Because the /t/ at the end of the word *what* is voiceless, the **'s** is pronounced /s/, not /z/.

Lastly notice that if a pronoun beginning with an H is stressed, the /h/ will be pronounced:

- *It's him* - /ɪts 'hɪm/

In the sentence above the word *him* is stressed, so we pronounce it with an /h/. If we see an accusative pronoun like *him* after the verb *BE*, it is very likely to be stressed.

---

<sup>**Transcription note**</sup>

<sup>I have used British English transcription here. The points about /z/, /s/ and /h/ are the same for standard British and American Englishes.</sup>

Comment: your answer is clear to me. Still, relistening to a podcast I hear "s" and not "z". Maybe you could check it out (see edit for the url)

Comment: @Gyonder Actually - I take that back -  she is a native speaker, I think, but she is speaking unnaturally slowly and over enunciating. The reason you hear an /s/-like sound there is because she uses an /h/ in *he* which makes the /z/ in *is* slightly devoiced. We still know it is a /z/ and not an /s/ though, because there is a full vowel in the word *is* (when a syllable ends in /s/ it causes the vowel to become short). If she was speaking naturally, she would be unlikely to use an /h/ in the word *he* in this position.